# How to correct styling of isotope page display in IE?

Tags: css, jquery-isotope

I'm working on a simple website using Twitter's Bootstrap css framework for the basic styling (don't know if this is relevant info).

I've made a simple filterable products page using isotope.js, which is working as expected in Chrome, Safari and Firefox on my Mac. However, something weird is happening in IE8 and IE9; the images get all scrunched up (they should be square, using WP featured image function), see [image](http://d.pr/Fu9G).

The URL of the site is: http://www.nieuwkerkonline.nl/het-bedrijf/producten/

Does anyone know what is causing this, and how I may be able to resolve it? The fact that the rounded corners and other CSS3 goodness get left out, I can live with, but the pictures defninitely need to display properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
```

to your `css` classes `.post`  and `.entry-content`